# Access-Control-Allow-Headers returning two values

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am having trouble submitting to an API when using IE 11.  I believe the problem is the API is returning TWO Access-Control-Allow-Headers in IE 11.  In Chrome and Firefox, it only returns one. Also, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin returns a URL in IE 11, but returns a * in Chrome and FF. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated as I have spend double digit hours trying to resolve with no success. The logic of what happens after submit is based on the response, but it is kicking out with errors on IE so that logic never gets executed ( SEC7123: Request header content-type was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list. - SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied. ).

IE 11 Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    bearer_token
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    authorization, x-date, Content-Type, if-none-match
Access-Control-Allow-Origin - https://this.that.com

Chrome and FF Response Headers (the ones that are different from IE):
Access-Control-Allow-Headers - authorization, x-date, etag, content-type, range, if-none-match
Access-Control-Allow-Origin - *

## Code being used to submit:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://this.that.com?firstname=test&lastname=test&email=test55@n2.com',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: '{}',
            xhrFields: {
            withCredentials:  true
            },
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            },

            success: function( data, status, jQxhr ){
            var thisResponse = jQxhr.responseText;
            var trimResp = thisResponse.slice(2, -2);
            thisParse = jQuery.parseJSON(trimResp);
            var thisStatus = thisParse.status;
            console.log(jQxhr);
            //alert(thisStatus);
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
console.log("readyState: " + jqXhr.readyState);
console.log("responseText: "+ jqXhr.responseText);
console.log("status: " + jqXhr.status);
console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
console.log(jqXhr.getAllResponseHeaders);
            }
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks for taking the time to read through this.

Cheers~
C

Comment: This topic sound interesting but your question is very specific. So we need more information because we cannot test this code in our environment. If you have any error message please also attache it to your question.

Comment: Thaks for the comment Teocci.  The errors are listed at the end of the first paragraph of the question.  For reference, here they are again  ( SEC7123: Request header content-type was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list. - SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied. ).